# Preventing the accidentally marking of all conflicts as resolved in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge-conflict-resolution

It doesn't happen too often, but every once in a while I'll fumble with my typing and accidentally invoke "hg resolve -m" without a file argument.  This then helpfully marks all the conflicts resolved.  Is there any way to prevent it from resolving without one or more file arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `pre-resolve` hook but you'd have to parse the arguments yourself to ensure that they are valid which could be tricky.

The relevant environment variables that you might need to look at are:

- `HG_ARGS` - the contents of the whole command line e.g. `resolve -m`
- `HG_OPTS` - a dictionary object containing options specified.  This would have an an entry called `mark` with a value of `True` if `-m` had been specified
- `HG_PATS` - this is the list of files specified

Depending upon the scripting language you would use, you should be able to test if `HG_OPTS` contains a value of `True` for `mark` and fail if it does and the `HG_PATS` array is empty.

It starts to get complicated when you take into account the `--include` and `--exclude` arguments.

If you specify the files to resolve as part of the `--include` option then the files to include would be in `HG_OPTS`, not `HG_PATS`.  Also, I don't know what would happen if you specified `hg resolve -m test.txt --exclude test.txt`.  I'd hope that it would not resolve anything but you'd need to test that.

Once you've parsed the command arguments, you'd return either 0 to allow the command or 1 to prevent it.  You should echo a reason for the failure if you return 1 to avoid confusion later.

If you don't know how to do this then you'd need to specify what OS and shell you are using for anyone to provide more specific help.